# How do I get the Aetherial Staff in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I get the Aetherial Staff in Skyrim? What should I do first to start the quest? I tried to Google it but the resources are limited and some websites are down.

Comment: Asking for people not to downvote tends to lead to more downvotes.  That said, *why* are your resources limited to this site?  There's a plethora of information available online, and there's no reason to make an attempt to find this out yourself before asking here.

Comment: Why are you limited to this site? Peculiar religion? Very specific learning disability? Crippling phobia of google after the minion incident? Either way, -1 for making me agree with @Frank.

Comment: I can't imagine a web filter that allows gaming.stackexchange.com but blocks uesp.net.

Comment: @Studoku I asked him about this on another question, he said "I can't google anything on wiki or any other gaming forums because I use a school iPad which things like wiki, and gaming sites are blocked. I don't have resources. I'm 13 and I don't have a phone. My options are pretty limited"

Comment: There's the whole of the internet.  **One** site is blocked.  I don't think it's possible to block each and every site that has data on Skyrim.  You need to at least *attempt* to figure this out yourself, not just say you can't.

Comment: Clearly, some users are not satisified with your explanation, Matthew. Is Google blocked? If not, you could try googling, and then if the top few results are blocked, say that you found that stuff but it was blocked. Perhaps that would help. Just some suggestions so you can get a little rep.

Comment: @Frank so I googled Aetherial staff, and I came up with websites like wikia, gameFAQs, YouTube, uesp, Reddit, nexusmods, and several other pages similar to those and they were blocked. Google is not blocked but MANY websites are

Comment: what a nice community ~

tell someone too look on google when they can answer it.

Comment: @Namikaze No, we're not saying to look on Google. We're saying we expect askers to try to figure it out themselves, so we can see there was an effort made. Just saying, "I can't" doesn't cut it.

Comment: @Frank I edited this question so it should look a bit better. But no completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Lost to the Ages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lost_to_the_Ages), the quest which leads you to the Aetherial forge, can be started either by entering [Arkngthamz](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arkngthamz) and talking to Katria, or by reading The Aetherium Wars.

The Aetherium Wars can be found in [several locations](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Aetherium_Wars), most notably the library in the College of Winterhold and the Bards College.